# Getting React error: "setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component" ONLY with Child Component

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I've been chasing this bug all day. I have a dead-simple React entry point, and a dead-simple component state change example component. If I put the component into the entry point, like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default class Template extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      collapsed: true,
    };
  }

  toggleNavbar() {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Collapsed: { this.state.collapsed ? 'true' : 'false' }</p>
        <button onClick={this.toggleNavbar}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <Template />,
  document.querySelector('#react-app'),
);
```

It works as expected. You click the toggle button, and the text changes back and forth between 'true' and 'false'. However, the minute I break it out into two separate files, giving me this for the entry point:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Template from './components/Template';

render(
  <Template />,
  document.querySelector('#react-app'),
);
```

and this for Template.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Template extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      collapsed: true,
    };
  }

  toggleNavbar() {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Collapsed: { this.state.collapsed ? 'true' : 'false' }</p>
        <button onClick={this.toggleNavbar}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any time I click on the button I get the following error in the console:

**build.js:23484 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Template component.**

... I've checked all of the other Stack Overflow answers for that error (and also searched around a ton), and none of them seem to be applicable here. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

side note: I've tried adding:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.isUnmounted = true;
}
```

and a `!this.isUnmounted` check before `setState()` and I still get the error.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried stripping a 'create-react-app' down to the bare bones and running your code in the created app, and it just works for me. This leads me to think it's more likely a problem resulting from building/bundling. My github repo for your problem is https://github.com/finbarrobrien/react-setstate

Comment: try this `onClick={() => {this.toggleNavbar()}}` . Also add jsx file extension to your import statement `import Template from './components/Template.jsx';`

Comment: @FinbarrO'B - thanks. Yes, it's a bundling problem. I located the problem after creating a brand new app from scratch (like you did) and setting everything up. Turns out I had an errant line in my .babelrc: `"plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]` I think what was happening was, that was conflicting with my webpack hot-reloading in some way. Anyway, removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue: my .babelrc contained this line:

```
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
```

And it was conflicting with the rest of my webpack hot-reloading setup. Removing that line did the trick. I think what was happening is that the component was getting rendered, but somehow react was getting confused about what was/wasn't mounted (maybe it was very quickly getting mounted, unmounted, and then re-mounted, and so the bound toggleClick function was trying to set state on an old version of the component? Unsure).

Anyway, the moral of the story is: the React code is fine. It was a problem with my config.